# Magento 2.1.1 how to add version number to css

Tags: magento2, css, header

I want to add `?v=20170721` after `css` file

> http://example.com/pub/static/_cache/merged/91eeca7a8ffa88b106ef85bd3a665d93.min.css?v=20170721

I tried to set "yes" in sign static files but this is not what I want

How to force the customers update their CSS in client side?

Answer (score 0):

I found out where to control the header content.

I create a preference and override the function `renderAssetGroup()` in `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer`

```
protected function renderAssetGroup(\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup $group)
{
    $groupAssets = $this->processMerge($group->getAll(), $group);

    $attributes = $this->getGroupAttributes($group);
    $attributes = $this->addDefaultAttributes(
        $group->getProperty(GroupedCollection::PROPERTY_CONTENT_TYPE),
        $attributes
    );

    $groupTemplate = $this->getAssetTemplate(
        $group->getProperty(GroupedCollection::PROPERTY_CONTENT_TYPE),
        $attributes
    );

    $version = '20170809';
    $getPath = $this->renderAssetHtml($groupTemplate, $groupAssets);
    if(strpos($getPath, '.css"') !== false){
        $getPath = str_replace('.css"', '.css?v='.$version.'"', $getPath);
    }
    if(strpos($getPath, '.js"') !== false){
        $getPath = str_replace('.js"', '.js?v='.$version.'"', $getPath);
    }

    $groupHtml = $getPath;
    $groupHtml = $this->processIeCondition($groupHtml, $group);
    return $groupHtml;
}
```